# How to reposition objects in Android layout?

Tags: android

I've added two controls, say Text Box.

But it is added side by side.

I want to move the objects, like in Visual Studio.

Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: can you post layout file

Comment: Please try to be clear if you want people here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Relative layout for placing your views, so that you can place them variably like left of,right of, above, below, align etc.

Answer (score 0):

You want one above the other?  Try RelativeLayout and you can specify layout_below.